# style.css wordpress template menu alignment

Tags: css, wordpress, stylesheet, wordpress-theming

I'm working on the stylesheet for a wordpress template (http://newwpthemes.com/techzilla-free-wordpress-theme/).  I would like the links in the "secondary menu" to be left aligned.  I have tried to add `float: left;` where I think it should be, but so far it has not worked.  You can see an example here: http://www.hafdal.dk/ - it is the menu that is placed below the slideshow.  Any idea where I need to modify the stylesheet?  I had to cut parts of the stylesheet out but I left the ones related to the menus.

```
/*
    Theme Name: TechZilla
    Theme URI: http://newwpthemes.com/techzilla-free-wordpress-theme/
    Description: Free News/Magazine WordPress theme by NewWpThemes
    Author: NewWpThemes
    Author URI: http://newwpthemes.com
    Version: 1.0
    Tags: gray, red, three-columns, left-right-sidebars
*/ 
/* INDEX:
    =GENERAL
    =LAYOUT
    =HEADER
    =MENUS
    =POST
    =SITEMAP
    =CONTACT FORM
    =SLIDER
    =WP-PAGENAVI
    =FOOTER
    =WIDGETS
    =COMMENTS
/* =GENERAL
-------------------------------------------------------------- */
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Abel);

body {
    background: url(images/background.png);
    color: #555555;
}

a {
    color: #EC2124;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

a:hover, a:focus {
    color: #000000;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:focus { 
    outline: none;
}

/* =LAYOUT
-------------------------------------------------------------- */

#container {
    width: 1200px;
    /* breytt úr 960px*/
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#main {
    padding: 15px;  
    background: #fff;
}

#main-fullwidth {
    padding: 15px;
    background: #fff;
}

#content {
    overflow: hidden;
    float: left;
    width: 700px;
    /* breytt úr 460px*/
    margin-left: 235px;
    /* breytt úr 235px*/
}

#sidebar-primary {
    overflow: hidden;
    float: left;
    width: 220px;
    margin-left: -935px;
  /* breytt úr -695px*/
}

#sidebar-secondary {
    overflow: hidden;
    float: right;
    width: 220px;
    margin-left: 15px;
}

/* =HEADER
-------------------------------------------------------------- */

#header {
    height: 60px;
    padding:30px 0;
    background: #FFFFFF;
}

.logo {
    float: left;
    margin: 2px 0 2px 15px;
}

.logo h1.site_title {
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif;
    font-size:48px;
    line-height: 40px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.logo h1.site_title a, .logo h1.site_title a:hover {
    color: #272324;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.logo h2.site_description {
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
    color: #272324;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
    line-height: 14px;
}

.header-right {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 15px;
}

#top-social-profiles {
    padding-top: 6px;
    height: 32px;
    text-align: right;

}
#top-social-profiles img {
    margin: 0 0 0 6px !important;
} 

#top-social-profiles img:hover {
    opacity: 0.8;
}
#top-social-profiles .widget-container {
  background: none;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}

/* =MENUS
-------------------------------------------------------------- */

/* Menu Primary
----------------------------*/

.menu-primary-container {
    float: left;
    padding:0;
    position:relative;
    height: 34px;
    z-index: 400;
    margin-top: 7px;
}

.menu-primary {
}

.menu-primary ul {
    min-width: 160px;
}

/* First Level - Menu Primary */

.menu-primary li a {
    color: #666666;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Abel', sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: normal;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    margin: 0 4px 0 0;
    border-top: 2px solid #FFFFFF;
}

.menu-primary li a:hover, .menu-primary li a:active, .menu-primary li a:focus, 
.menu-primary li:hover > a, .menu-primary li.current-cat > a, .menu-primary li.current_page_item > a, .menu-primary li.current-menu-item > a {
    color: #E82425;
    outline: 0;
    border-top: 2px solid #E82425;
}

/* Child Levels - Menu Primary */

.menu-primary li li a {
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: none;
    background: #666666;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-weight: normal;
    border-top:0;
}

.menu-primary li li a:hover, .menu-primary li li a:active, .menu-primary li li a:focus, 
.menu-primary li li:hover > a, .menu-primary li li.current-cat > a, .menu-primary li li.current_page_item > a, .menu-primary li li.current-menu-item > a {

    color: #fff;
    background: #7F7F7F;
    outline: 0;
    border-bottom:0;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-top:0;
}


/* Arrows Menu Primary */

.menu-primary a.sf-with-ul {
    padding-right: 20px;
    min-width: 1px;
}
.menu-primary  .sf-sub-indicator {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    right: 0;
    top:  0;
    padding: 9px 10px 0 0;
}

.menu-primary  li li .sf-sub-indicator {
    padding: 9px 10px 0 0;
}

/* Shadows Menu Primary */

.wrap-menu-primary .sf-shadow ul {
    background: url('images/menu-primary-shadow.png') no-repeat bottom right;
}

/* Menu Secondary
----------------------------*/

.menu-secondary-container {
    position:relative;
    height: 38px;
    z-index: 300;
    background: url(images/menu-secondary-bg.png) left top repeat-x;
}

.menu-secondary {}

.menu-secondary ul {
    min-width: 160px;
}

/* First Level - Menu Secondary */
.menu-secondary li a {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 10px 15px 14px 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Abel', sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.menu-secondary li a:hover, .menu-secondary li a:active, .menu-secondary li a:focus, 
.menu-secondary li:hover > a, .menu-secondary li.current-cat > a, .menu-secondary li.current_page_item > a, .menu-secondary li.current-menu-item > a {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background: url(images/menu-secondary-bg.png) left -138px repeat-x;
    outline: 0;
}

/* Child Levels - Menu Secondary */

.menu-secondary li li a {
    color: #fff;
    background: #414141;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    text-transform: none;
    margin: 0;
    font-weight: normal;
}

.menu-secondary li li a:hover, .menu-secondary li li a:active, .menu-secondary li li a:focus, 
.menu-secondary li li:hover > a, .menu-secondary li li.current-cat > a, .menu-secondary li li.current_page_item > a, .menu-secondary li li.current-menu-item > a {
color: #fff;
    background: #EC2124;
    outline: 0;
}

/* Arrows - Menu Secondary */

.menu-secondary a.sf-with-ul {
    padding-right: 26px;
    min-width: 1px;
}
.menu-secondary  .sf-sub-indicator {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    right: 0;
    top:  0;
    padding: 9px 13px 0 0;
}

.menu-secondary li li .sf-sub-indicator {
    padding: 9px 13px 0 0;
}

/* Shadows - Menu Secondary */

.wrap-menu-secondary .sf-shadow ul {
    background: url('images/menu-secondary-shadow.png') no-repeat bottom right;
}

/* =POST
-------------------------------------------------------------- */

/* Post General
----------------------------*/

.post {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.page, .post-single {
    border-bottom: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.title {
    color: #333333;
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Abel', sans-serif;
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.title a {
    color: #333333;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.title a:hover {
    color: #EC2124;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.entry {
    line-height: 20px;
}

.featured_image {
    padding: 6px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background: #fff;
}

.page-title {
    color: #333;
    margin: 0px 0 10px 0;
    padding: 0 0 10px 0;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #ddd;
}

/* Post Metas
----------------------------*/

.postmeta-primary {
    color: #999999;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 18px;
    padding: 0 0 10px 0;
}

.postmeta-secondary {
    color: #999999;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 18px;
    padding: 0 0 10px 0;
}

.postmeta-primary span, .postmeta-secondary span {
    background: url(images/meta-separator.png) left center no-repeat;
    padding:3px 0 3px 10px;
}


.postmeta-primary span:first-child, .postmeta-secondary span:first-child {
    background: none;
    padding-left: 0;
}

/* Read More
----------------------------*/

.readmore {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    float: right;
}

.readmore a {
    color: #6D6D6D;
    background: #F2F2F2;
    padding: 8px 14px;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 12px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.readmore a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background: #EC2124;
    text-decoration: none;
}

/* =SITEMAP
-------------------------------------------------------------- */
.sitemap {
}

.sitemap-col {
    width: 30%;
    padding: 0 0 0 10px;
}

.sitemap-col-archives {
    width: 45%;
    padding: 0 0 0 10px;
}

.sitemap h2 {
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #ddd;
    padding: 0 0 10px 0;
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}

.sitemap h3 {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}

.sitemap-list {
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 22px;
}

.sitemap-list, .sitemap-list ul {
    padding: 0 0 0 20px;
}

/* =CONTACT FORM
-------------------------------------------------------------- */
.contact-form {
}

.contact-form-label {
    width: 90px;    
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 7px 0;
}

.contact-form-input {
    margin-left: 90px;    
}

.contact-form input[type=text] {
    padding: 6px;
    width: 60%;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background: #fff;
}

.contact-form input[type=submit] {
    padding: 5px 50px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background: #eee;
}
.contact-form textarea {
    width: 96%;
    padding: 6px;
    height: 160px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background: #fff;
}

.contact-form-required {
    color: red;
}

/* =SLIDER
-------------------------------------------------------------- */

.fp-slider {
    margin: 0 0 15px 0;
}

.fp-slides-container {}

.fp-slides, .fp-thumbnail, .fp-prev-next, .fp-nav {
    width: 1170px;
    /* breytt úr 930px*/
}

.fp-slides, .fp-thumbnail {
    height: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

.fp-title {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 0 0 2px 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.fp-title a, .fp-title a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.fp-content {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: #111;
    opacity: 0.7;
    filter: alpha(opacity = 70);
    padding: 10px 15px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.fp-content p {
    color: #fff;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 18px;
}

.fp-more,  .fp-more:hover{
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.fp-nav {
    height: 12px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px 0;
    background: #333;
}

.fp-pager a { 
    background-image: url(images/featured-pager.png); 
    cursor:pointer;  
    margin: 0 8px 0 0; 
    padding: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 12px; 
    height: 12px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-indent: -999px; 
    background-position: 0 0;
    float: none;
    line-height: 1;
    opacity: 0.7;
    filter: alpha(opacity = 70);
}

.fp-pager a:hover, .fp-pager a.activeSlide  { 
    text-decoration: none;
    background-position: 0 -112px;
    opacity: 1.0;
    filter: alpha(opacity = 100);
}

.fp-prev-next-wrap {
    position: relative; 
    z-index: 200; 
}

.fp-prev-next {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 130px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 37px;  
}

.fp-prev {
    float:left;
    margin-left: 14px;
    width:37px;
    height:37px;
    background:url(images/featured-prev.png) left top no-repeat;
    opacity: 0.6;
    filter: alpha(opacity = 60);
}

.fp-prev:hover {
    opacity: 0.8;
    filter: alpha(opacity = 80);
}

 .fp-next {
    float:right;
    width:36px;
    height:37px;
    margin-right: 14px;
    background:url(images/featured-next.png) right top no-repeat;
    opacity: 0.6;
    filter: alpha(opacity = 60);
}

.fp-next:hover {
    opacity: 0.8;
    filter: alpha(opacity = 80);
}

/* =WP-PAGENAVI
-------------------------------------------------------------- */

.wp-pagenavi {
    float: left;
}

.wp-pagenavi a, .wp-pagenavi span {
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 5px 8px;
    margin: 2px;
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 15px;
    float: left;
}

.wp-pagenavi a, .wp-pagenavi a:link, .wp-pagenavi a:active {
    color: #333333;
    background:none;
}

.wp-pagenavi span.current {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #fff;
    background:#EC2124;
}

.wp-pagenavi a:hover {
    color: #333333;
    background:#DEDEDE;
}

.wp-pagenavi span.pages {
    color: #333333;
    background: none;
    padding: 4px 8px 4px 0;
}

.wp-pagenavi span.extend {
    background:transparent;
    color: #333333;
    background: none;
}

/* =FOOTER
-------------------------------------------------------------- */

#footer {
    margin:10px 0 15px 0;
}

#copyrights {
    color: #434141;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px 0;
}

#copyrights a {
    color: #434141;
} 

#copyrights a:hover {
    color: #434141;
    text-decoration: none;
} 

#credits {
    color: #717171;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 11px;
    padding: 10px 0 0 0;
}

#credits a {
    color: #717171;
    text-decoration: none;
} 

#credits a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #717171;
}

/* Footer Widgets
----------------------------*/

#footer-widgets {
    background: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 20px 0 0 0;
    margin-top: 6px;
}

.footer-widget-box {
    width: 400px;
    /* breytt úr 300px*/
    float: left;
    margin-left: 15px;
}

.footer-widget-box-last {

}

/* Footer Widgets Color */

#footer-widgets .widget-container {

}

/* Footer Widgets Links */

#footer-widgets .widget-container a {

}

#footer-widgets .widget-container a:hover {

}

/* Footer Widget Title */

#footer-widgets .widgettitle {

}

#footer-widgets .widgettitle, #footer-widgets .widgettitle a, #footer-widgets .widgettitle a:hover {

}

/* Footer List Items */

#footer-widgets .widget ul li {

}

/* Footer Widgets Tabs */

#footer-widgets .tabs-widget li a {

}

#footer-widgets .tabs-widget li a:hover, #footer-widgets .tabs-widget li a.tabs-widget-current {

}

/* Footer Widgets Seaarch */

#footer-widgets #search {

}

#footer-widgets #search #s {

}


/* =WIDGETS
-------------------------------------------------------------- */

/* Widgets Defaults
----------------------------*/

.widget-container {
    list-style-type: none;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0 0 15px 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #666666;
    font-size: 13px;
}

.widget-container a {
    color: #666666;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.widget-container a:hover {
    color: #478AF8;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.widgettitle {
    background: url(images/background.png) left top repeat-x;
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
    padding: 8px 0 8px 10px;
    border-left: 4px solid #EC2124;
}

.widgettitle, .widgettitle a, .widgettitle a:hover {
    color: #414445;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 20px;
    font-family: 'Abel', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.widget ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.widget ul li {
    padding: 0 0 9px 0px;
    margin: 0 0 8px 0;
}

/* Search
----------------------------*/

#search {
    border: 1px solid #D8D8D8;
    background: #fff url(images/search.png) 99% 50% no-repeat;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 6px 24px 6px 6px;
}

#search #s {
    background: none;
    color: #979797;
    border: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    outline: none;
}

#content-search {
    width: 300px;
    padding: 15px 0;
}

/* Wp Calendar
----------------------------*/

#wp-calendar td:hover, #wp-calendar #today {
    background: #478AF8;
    color: #fff;
}

#wp-calendar td:hover a, #wp-calendar #today a {
    color: #fff;
}

/* Text Widget
----------------------------*/

.textwidget {
    line-height: 18px;
}

/* 125x125 Banners Widget
----------------------------*/

.banners-125 {
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: -10px;
}

.banners-125 img {
    margin: 0 5px 5px 5px;
}


/* Posts Widget
----------------------------*/

.posts-widget ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 10px 0 0 0;
}

.posts-widget ul li {
    list-style-type: none; 
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0 0 15px 0; 
    margin: 0 0 15px 0;

}

.posts-widgettitle {
    font-weight: bold; 
    padding: 0 0 5px 0; 
    margin: 0; 
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.posts-widgettitle a {}

.posts-widgettitle a:hover {}

.posts-widget-meta { 
    font-style: italic;  
    padding: 0 0 5px 0;
}

.posts-widget-entry {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif; 
    line-height: 20px;
}

.posts-widget-more {
    font-weight: bold;
}

.posts-widget-more:hover {}

.posts-widget-featured-image {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 4px;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.posts-widget .alignleft {
    margin: 0 8px 8px 0;
}

.posts-widget .alignright {
    margin: 0 0 8px 8px;
}

.posts-widget .aligncenter {
    margin-bottom: 8px;
}

/* Comments Widget
----------------------------*/

.comments-widget ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0; 
    margin: 10px 0 0 0;
}

.comments-widget ul li {
    list-style-type: none; 
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0 0 10px 0; 
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;

}

.comments-widget-author {
    text-decoration: none; 
    font-weight: bold; 
    padding: 0 0 5px 0; 
    margin: 0;
}

.comments-widget-author:hover {}

.comments-widget-entry {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif; 
    line-height: 20px;
}

.comments-widget-more {
    font-weight: bold; 
}

.comments-widget-more:hover {}

.comments-widget-avatar {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 4px;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.comments-widget .alignleft {
    margin: 0 8px 0 0;
}

.comments-widget .alignright {
    margin: 0 0 0 8px;
}

.comments-widget .aligncenter {
    margin-bottom: 8px;
}

/* Info Box Widget
----------------------------*/

.infobox-widget ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.infobox-widget ul li {
    list-style-type: none; 
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0; 
    margin: 5px 0 0 0;
}

.infobox-widget ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.infobox-widget-description {
    line-height: 20px;
}

.infobox-widget-more {
    font-weight: bold;    
}

.infobox-widget-more:hover {   
}


.infobox-widget .alignleft {
    margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
}

.infobox-widget .alignright {
    margin: 0 0 10px 10px;
}

.infobox-widget .aligncenter {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.infobox-widget .inbottom {
    margin-top: 10px;
}

/* Social Profiles Widget
----------------------------*/
.social-profiles-widget img {
    margin: 0 4px 0 0;
} 

.social-profiles-widget img:hover {
    opacity: 0.8;
} 

/* Tabs Widget
----------------------------*/

.tabs-widget {
    list-style: none; 
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
    padding: 0; 
    height: 26px;
}

.tabs-widget li {
    list-style: none; 
    list-style-type: none; 
    margin: 0 0 0 4px; 
    padding: 0; 
    float: left;
}

.tabs-widget li:first-child {
    margin: 0;
}

.tabs-widget li a {
    color: #EC2124;
    background: url(images/tabs-bg.png) left top repeat-x;
    padding: 6px 16px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 12px;
}

.tabs-widget li a:hover, .tabs-widget li a.tabs-widget-current {
    background: #EC2124;
    color: #fff;
}

.tabs-widget-content {
}

/* Tweets Widget
----------------------------*/

.tweets-widget ul {
    list-style-type: none; 
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0; 
    line-height: 20px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif; 
}

.tweets-widget ul li {
    list-style-type: none;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0; 
    margin: 15px 0 0 0; 
}

.tweets-widget ul li:first-child {
    margin-top: 5px;
}

.tweets-widget li.tweets-bird {
    padding-left: 24px;
    background: url(images/tweets.png) left 2px no-repeat;
}

.tweets-widget a {}

.tweets-widget a:hover {}

a.tweets-widget-time {
    text-decoration: underline; 
}

a.tweets-widget-time:hover {
    text-decoration: none; 
}

/* Facebook Widget
----------------------------*/

.facebook-widget {
    list-style-type: none; 
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0;
}


/* Children */

.commentlist .children li {
    border: none;
    margin: 0;
}

.nocomments {
    display: none;
}

#comments .pingback {
    margin-bottom: 18px;
    padding-bottom: 18px;
}

.commentlist li.comment+li.pingback {
    margin-top: -6px;
}

#comments .pingback p {
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 18px;
    display:block;
    margin: 0;
}

#comments .pingback .url {
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 13px;
}
/* =END
-------------------------------------------------------------- */
```

Comment: What do you mean with "left aligned"? Are you refering to the text on the links or to the whole blogroll? I ask that because I already see the text left-aligned on your link.

Comment: Sorry for not formulating this properly.  What I mean is that the Pages (Genealogy, Íslenska, English and Dansk) are centered in the black field (container).  I would like them to be left aligned, i.e. on the far left end of the black field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to have the contents of the `menu-secondary-container` div left aligned?

Looks like those links (Genealogy, Íslenska, English and Dansk) aren't floating under the logo image. Try adding this to your css:

```
.menu-secondary-container {
   clear:  both;
}
```